# Multiple choice question about a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ bigger than $\aleph_0$

Tags: set-theory

I have four options and should choose one. In the question: $\mathbb R$ – real numbers, $\mathbb Q$ - rational numbers.

Given that $A$ is a subset of $\mathbb R$ and $|A|\gt\aleph_0$, which option is correct?

> A. $|A\cup\mathbb Q|\gt|A\setminus\mathbb Q|$
>
> B. $|A\cap(\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q)|\gt\aleph_0$
>
> C. $|\mathbb R\setminus A|\le\aleph_0$
>
> D. None of the options A, B, C is correct.

After the exam I found that A is not true using contradiction like $A=\mathbb R$ so $A$ option not true for sure.

B I didn't find a contradiction so I chose B (I don't know how to prove this).

C also not true, I took $A=(0,1)$ (real numbers between $0$ to $1$) so $|\mathbb R\setminus A| \gt \aleph_0$ .

So I don't know if its B option or D. Can you please help me?

Comment: Um... You need to heavily edit your question, and even then the question won't necessarily be accepted here, as it is one of those "problem statement"/"please solve a problem for me" questions.

Comment: I've given it my best, please check if the edit is correct. As I said, this won't necessarily spark the interest of the people to answer. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). You may, for example, note what you know about cardinal numbers, whether you have a hunch which option (A-D) is correct, whether you've managed to disprove one of the options etc. Hint: C is quite easy to disprove.

Comment: look i dont fluent in english its difficult to me to explain this subject in english
i tried my best, i think the answer is 2 found that A and C not right. i after this exam, so i just want to be sure. i dont want other people do my exam cause i after this. just to know if i right, if you guys dont like  this kind of quistion here you just can tell me

Comment: Yep, the second option B looks promising. Have you tried to prove it? Or can you think of a counterexample? In other words, what makes you think that B is the answer? Also, why do you think A and C are not right? (Have you got, for example, counterexamples for those?)

Comment: for real i dont know how to prove that. i just didnt find any a contradiction to that. so i chosed B

Comment: At least please add to your question what you've just told me, with any proofs you may have that A and C are not right - this at least makes it obvious that you know you are choosing between B and D.

Comment: i will thank you, i am new here don't be that Hard to newbies :)

Comment: You have no idea how many newbies we get here who just want their work (homework, even exam :O) done for them. We've got to have *some* standard who to help. The above "how to ask a good question" is a part of this.

Comment: i am sure! so sorry for that. i just edited my thread is that ok/better now? -should i start new thread and delete this one? i am sure no one will enter this thead with 3 downvotes

Comment: Thanks a lot, let's try to see what will happen with this question. I've edited it to look prettier and flagged to reconsider for reopening.

Comment: Hint: Assume B is false and use $A = (A\cap (\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q)) \cup (A \cap \Bbb Q)$

Comment: So if i assume B false and using A as you mention A must be uncountable and we get contradiction for this assume.. right?. But i am not sure why using this definition for A if we assue B false. thanks

Answer (score 1):

What does B say in English? It says that every uncountable set of reals contains uncountable many irrationals.

Suppose $A$ was as described but contained only countably many irrationals, then $$|A| \leq |\mathbb{Q}| + |A \cap (\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q})| = \aleph_0$$ since rationals and irrationals form a partition. This is a contradiction, hence $A$ must contain uncountably many irrationals.

Comment: ok i think i got it, but not sure. if we try to Contradicting B we get a contradiction to the given data.
if we take A to be countable its must be $| A|\le\aleph_0$
and in that way we get a contradiction to the given data.
So the answer must be B.